# how to wrap html tag around image tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to convert below html image tag

```
<img src="img-1.jpg" width="290" height="420" class="frameImage" />
```

to following code using jquery.

```
<table class="frame" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="border-top" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-left"></td>
    <td><div class="image-frame"><img src="img-1.jpg" width="290" height="420" class="frameImage" />
        <div class="top-left"></div>
        <div class="top-right"></div>
        <div class="bottom-right"></div>
        <div class="bottom-left"></div>
      </div></td>
    <td class="border-right"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-bottom" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: it looks like he wants to put a special border around it

Comment: That's so much HTML, it would be better to use that in the first place, or generate it server-side.

Answer (score 2):

1. Append the whole table without the image to the document.
2. Find div with class 'image-frame' and place the image inside it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img[src=img-1.jpg]').before('<table class="frame" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="border-top" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-left"></td>
    <td><div class="image-frame"><img src="img-1.jpg" width="290" height="420" class="frameImage" />
        <div class="top-left"></div>
        <div class="top-right"></div>
        <div class="bottom-right"></div>
        <div class="bottom-left"></div>
      </div></td>
    <td class="border-right"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="border-bottom" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>').remove();
```

Comment: Would be better if you use .frameImage as the selector.

Comment: .frameImage selects all elements with this class. img[src=img-1.jpg] selects exactly the image tag with this image. I think the code is just an example. It should more exact.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
    $('.image-frame').html('<img src="img-1.jpg" width="290" height="420" class="frameImage" /%gt;')
```

but it would require you to print the table first and then insert the image into the table

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but you may be interested in [jQuery-ImageFrame](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-imageframe/wiki/Readme).